# Php and MySQL GROUP_CONCAT with separator comma and search where concat by comma

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation, group-concat

Is it that possible to select in Group_concat with separator comma
and search where concat by comma
Here My sample of mysql :

```
products_attributes_id  |products_id|   options_id|     options_values_id 
39                  |   31      |       3     |         3   
35                  |   30      |       2     |         2   
38                  |   30      |       1     |         1   
40                  |   31      |       2     |         2   
41                  |   30      |       1     |         4   
42                  |   30      |       1     |         5   
43                  |   31      |       1     |         4
```

I want to GROUP_CONCAT options_values_id

SELECT * , GROUP_CONCAT(options_values_id SEPARATOR ',') FROM  `products_attributes` GROUP by products_id

```
products_attributes_id  |   products_id |   options_id  |   options_values_id   |   options_values_id
35                  |   30          |   2           |   2                   |   2,1,4,5
39                  |   31          |   3           |   3                   |   3,2,4
```

Now my problem is How I will find the product_id by searching ( option_values_id with comma) if my value is 1,2 or 2,4 then I will get only product_id=30.
But if I got value 1,3 I will get nothing. Because product_id 30 don't have option_values_id 3
and product_id 31 don't have option_values_id 1.

I try this code but I can't get the product_id

```
    SELECT * , GROUP_CONCAT( options_values_id
SEPARATOR ',' )
FROM `products_attributes` WHERE CONCAT(',',options_values_id,',') LIKE '%,1,2,%'
GROUP BY products_id
```

Comment: Maybe there is a way to do this without using `GROUP_CONCAT`? Can you give us some more background info?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    products_id , 
    GROUP_CONCAT(options_values_id SEPARATOR ',') as ops 
FROM 
    products_attributes 
GROUP by 
    products_id
HAVING
    FIND_IN_SET('1',ops)
    OR FIND_IN_SET('3',ops)
```

Comment: "Try this" answers are low value on Stack Overflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.