# Search GROUP_CONCAT for filtering data

Tags: mysql, sql, search, having

I want to be able to search for my products (search in either the product name or product "codes"), and then filter in those results as well.

I don't know what to search for in Google or SO, every time I get [Search GROUP_CONCAT using LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806830/search-group-concat-using-like) or [Php and MySQL GROUP_CONCAT with separator comma and search where concat by comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958908/php-and-mysql-group-concat-with-separator-comma-and-search-where-concat-by-comma) come up, but I can't seem to wrap my head around `HAVING` without getting an error in my database. I'm not sure if this is even possible or if I'm just way off.

My tables are like so:

**Products Table**

```
+------------+--------------+----------------+-------------------------+---------------+
| product_id | product_name | product_status | product_date_available  | product_type  |
+------------+--------------+----------------+-------------------------+---------------+
|          1 | Rug          |              1 | 2020-01-24              |             0 |
|          2 | Scraper      |              1 | 2020-03-15              |             0 |
|          3 | Shovel       |              0 | 2019-04-24              |             0 |
|          4 | Bucket       |              1 | 2030-01-01              |             0 |
|          5 | Dog          |              1 | 2018-04-27              |             0 |
|          6 | Digging      |              1 | 2020-01-01              |             1 |
+------------+--------------+----------------+-------------------------+---------------+
```

**Products Category table**

```
+------------+-------------+
| product_id | category_id |
+------------+-------------+
|          1 |          17 |
|          2 |          22 |
|          3 |          22 |
|          4 |          17 |
+------------+-------------+
```

**Products Tag Table**

```
+------------+--------+
| product_id | tag_id |
+------------+--------+
|          1 |     11 |
|          2 |      6 |
|          3 |      7 |
|          4 |      7 |
+------------+--------+
```

**Products Codes Table**

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| code_id | product_id | code_value |
+---------+------------+------------+
|       1 |          1 | 47012.000  |
|       2 |          1 | 47012.001  |
|       3 |          2 | 47013.000  |
|       4 |          3 | 47014.000  |
|       5 |          3 | 47014.001  |
|       6 |          3 | 47014.002  |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

**Product Variants Values Table**

```
+-------+------------+----------+
| pv_id | product_id | value_id |
+-------+------------+----------+
|     1 |          1 |        7 |
|     2 |          1 |        6 |
|     3 |          1 |       10 |
|     4 |          2 |        7 |
|     5 |          3 |       10 |
|     6 |          3 |        7 |
|     7 |          3 |       12 |
|     8 |          2 |       14 |
+-------+------------+----------+
```

This is what I've tried but can't get to work:

**Search for product code**

```sql
SELECT p.product_id,
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT code_value) FROM `me_product_variant_codes` WHERE `product_id` = p.product_id) AS codes,
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT value_id) FROM `me_product_variant_values` WHERE `product_id` = p.product_id) AS variant_values,
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag_id) FROM `me_product_tags` WHERE `product_id` = p.product_id) AS product_tags
    FROM me_product AS p
    WHERE (p.product_status = '1' AND p.product_date_available <= CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'SYSTEM', '+13:00') AND p.product_type = '0')
    AND ((LOWER(p.product_name) LIKE '%47012%')
    GROUP BY p.product_id
    HAVING codes LIKE '%47012%'
    AND HAVING variant_values IN(7, 10)
    AND HAVING product_tags IN(11)
    ORDER BY product_name DESC
    LIMIT 24
```

I'm well aware that I probably have this very wrong, but after weeks of research, I don't seem to be any closer to finding an answer on how to make this work.

So I expect as an example if I search for `47012` it will return the following based on the example data above.

```
+------------+----------------------+----------------+--------------+
| product_id |        codes         | variant_values | product_tags |
+------------+----------------------+----------------+--------------+
|          1 | 47012.000, 47012.001 | 7, 6           |           11 |
+------------+----------------------+----------------+--------------+
```

But I'm currently getting this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY p.product_id
    HAVING codes LIKE '%47012%'
    AND HAVING variant_v' at line 8
```

Even trying a simple version of my query to at least get some result gives me an error

**Simplified query**

```sql
SELECT p.product_id,
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT code_value) FROM `me_product_variant_codes` WHERE `code_product_id` = p.product_id) AS codes
    FROM me_product AS p
    WHERE (p.product_status = '1' AND p.product_date_available <= CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'SYSTEM', '+13:00') AND p.product_type = '0')
    AND ((LOWER(p.product_name) LIKE '%47012%')
    GROUP BY p.product_id
    HAVING codes LIKE '%47012%'
    ORDER BY p.product_name DESC
    LIMIT 24
```

Gives me this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY p.product_id
    HAVING codes LIKE '%47012%'
    ORDER BY p.product_n' at line 6
```

The other issue I've just noticed is that I'm not sure how this will return results if it matches the `product_name` OR one of the `codes` values

Comment: You mention that it doesn't work, but you never explained what the problem is.  Please show the current and expected output, at the very least.

Comment: Actually you only need to define `HAVING` once then continue with `AND`. Similar to how you do `WHERE.. AND .. AND ...`  . And since `product_tags` and `product_name` is a result from `GROUP_CONCAT`, using `IN (val1, val2)` might return nothing

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks, I never even thought about that. My brain fried just trying to work out how to word this question. Updated information :)

Comment: @tcadidot0 Ah, thanks, I hadn't even thought about the `AND` in the `HAVING` working the same. I'm not sure what you mean by `product_name` being a result of `GROUP_CONCAT`? It's one of the columns in the products table. So you're saying that I can't filter using the `IN()` function then?

Comment: Your `HAVING` logic is dubious, and it appears that some of the conditions you want a logical or while others you want a logical and.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've never worked with `HAVING` or even knew about it until a few weeks ago, so I'm not entirely sure how it works. Pretty much my only logical `OR` I want is between the `product_name` OR `codes`, and the rest of them should be logical `ANDS` because they are specifically just for filtering so can change.

Comment: This isn't enough information for us to know what you want.

Comment: @dpDesignz Sorry, my bad.. not `product_name` column. Only `product_tags` which was a `GROUP_CONCAT` result so using `IN`- especially `IN(val1,val2)` might not return anything on that field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get rid of all those correlated subqueries and instead use joins to subqueries which compute the various CSV terms:

```
SELECT
    p.product_id,
    COALESCE(vc.codes, 'NA') AS codes,
    COALESCE(vv.variant_values, 'NA') AS variant_values,
    COALESCE(pt.product_tags, 'NA') AS product_tags
FROM me_product AS p
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT code_value) AS codes
    FROM me_product_variant_codes
    WHERE code_value LIKE '%47012%'
    GROUP BY product_id
) vc
    ON vc.product_id = p.product_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT value_id) AS variant_values
    FROM me_product_variant_values
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN value_id = 7 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
           COUNT(CASE WHEN value_id = 10 THEN 1 END) > 0
) vv
    ON vv.product_id = p.product_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag_id) AS product_tags
    FROM me_product_tags
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN tag_id = 11 THEN 1 END) > 0
) pt
    ON pt.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE
    p.product_status = '1' AND
    p.product_date_available <= CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'SYSTEM', '+13:00') AND
    p.product_type = '0' AND
    LOWER(p.product_name) LIKE '%47012%';
```

Comment: You can make this query much better if you add unique index for Category and Tag tables - so you don`t have to make GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag_id)

Comment: @Crusader interesting, are you able to elaborate here? Does adding a unique index mean I can just remove the `DISTINCT` or what does that actually do? I just copied that code from one of the other articles I originally linked.

Comment: I can't really update my answer without knowing your logic.  If you only want certain values to appear in the CSV, then this restriction should be introduced via a `WHERE` clause in the subqueries.  If, on the other hand, you only require certain values to be present in the CSV, but there are no restrictions on other values also appearing, then you should add a `HAVING` clause to the subqueries.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen perfect, thanks so much for this! It's definitely got me where I need to be for now and I think I understand how my logic should work now to build the rest of my query. I really appreciate it. :)